# Setting the orientation for only 1 fragment in my activity while the rest is in portrait

Tags: android, android-fragments, orientation

My app needs to be in portrait mode so I set it in the manifest by:

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

But I just recently added another fragment (FragA) that just looks and functions 10x better in landscape.  Is there something I can put inside of my FragA to just make that fragment in landscape while retaining the rest of the app in portrait or by doing this will I have to add something to my other fragments to keep them retained as portrait?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Orientation attribute is per activity so you can declare the orientation for only the activity  that contains the fragment so that it is in landscape and the rest of the activities will remain as they are.

Comment: so basically my best bet would be to just create another activity and then in my manifest just put that as:android:screenOrientation="landscape"?

Comment: Yes that will ensure that your functionality will never fail.

Comment: @DineshVenkata but I don't want to rotate only fragment not activity what to do

Answer (score 115):

Use the following code line in the fragment where you want a specific (in this case portrait) orientation.

```
getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(
            ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

If you want to have a orientation in a fragment, that is based on the way the user holds his device, then use the following code line.

```
getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(
                ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED);
```

Hope, this will give you the intended solution.

Comment: I use this in the activity code just before the fragment transaction is commited. Using it inside the fragment onAttach()/onStop() doesn't work good. I test on KitKat atm.

Comment: Correction: Looks like the better place to call setRequestedOrientation() is inside OnBackStackChangedListener after checking what fragment is currently active. And this approach leads to better visual transition when activity is restarted.

Comment: I have it working using those lines in fragment's onCreateView()

Comment: Is this the correct way of restricting Orientations in Fragments ?

Comment: It works, however if you are using weights in your layout the weights may be from the wrong orientation despite which way the layout is being rendered...

Comment: @IvanMorgillo it's dangerous to call `getActivity()` inside of `onCreateView()` as it's not guaranteed your activity will be non-null.

Comment: @Maurizio what do you suggest to be sure to get the proper context?

Comment: use it in onAttach(Activity activity).

Comment: this solution only apply for activity, not fragments. if one activity have 2 fragments, one for portrait, one for landscape. can not apply this case.

Comment: @HuyTower I agree with you. Is there any solution for the scenario you are talking about?

Comment: @LoveForDroid : 1 activity should go along with 1 fragment. It is ok.

Comment: This is should be the accepted answer. Set it in onCreate & unset in onPause.

Comment: use android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" if your activity restart with config changes

Answer (score 25):

In each of your fragments, set the requested orientation.

Reference doc: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ActivityInfo.html

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

   // Fragment locked in portrait screen orientation
   getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);    

   // Fragment locked in landscape screen orientation
   getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

   // Fragment screen orientation normal both portait and landscape       
   getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

So I'm dealing with this issue now. We have only **portrait** mode application (for now). But there is one fragment that needs to be in **landscape**. We are using single Activity approach so the accepted answer will not help me.

The fastest solution I could think of is this one.

```
private var swappingOrientation = false

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    if(savedInstanceState == null) {
        swappingOrientation = true
        activity?.apply {
            requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE
        }
    }
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()

    if(!swappingOrientation) {
        activity?.apply {
            requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT
        }
    }
    swappingOrientation = false
}
```

You hold the information if you are swapping orientation or not in **swappingOrientation** variable. At the beggining when the fragment is created it will change orientation, only when there is no saved state. And orientation is changed back again only when it is not being currently changed.

This is a super quick solution and it can produce screen blinking when you return to previous fragment. I also did not fully test it so it can have other issues, so keep that in mind.

Answer (score 3):

First Fragment:

```
@Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    }
```

Second Fragment:

```
     @Override
        public void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
 getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED);
   }
```

Comment: fragment onResume not working setRequestedOrientation

Answer (score 2):

This is old question but answering this just incase anyone wanted the solution as the OP needed. The simple way to achieve this is as follows.

```
public class LandscapeFragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

       getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(
              ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    }

   @Override
   public View onDestroyView() {
       super.onDestroyView();

       getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(
             ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

}
```

Then `extend` this `LandscapeFragment` from any of your fragment to which you want to launch it in landscape mode.

Comment: why would you call super.onViewCreated from onCreateView() ?

Comment: @KaranSharma thats a typo, corrected it. Thanks for pointing it.

Answer (score 0):

ok after i almost blew my head off this worked for me with jetpack navigation components fragments

so this is the base fragment class

```
abstract class BaseFragment : Fragment(){   

var rotated = false

fun rotate() {
        val currentOrientation = activity?.resources?.configuration?.orientation //this is diffrent from  Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE
        Log.e("currentOrientation--->",currentOrientation.toString())

        if (currentOrientation != null) {
            if (currentOrientation !=  Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
                activity?.requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE
            }else{
                rotated=true
            }
        }else{
            //impossible
            activity?.requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE
        }
    }


    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        if (rotated)
            activity?.requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED
    }

}
```

and i put this in any fragment i wish it to be landscaped

```
override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    rotate()
}
```