# Two fragments on one screen with different orientation

Tags: android

Is it possible to have 2 fragment on one screen with different orientation ( one reverse portraite and one regular protraite).
screenOrientation or setRequestedScreenOrientation affect both.

Comment: no it is not possible. The orientation is driven by the Activity

Comment: you can use android:rotation to 270 degree to the root layout of your fragment

Comment: see the answer here with maximum upvotes :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12704009/setting-the-orientation-for-only-1-fragment-in-my-activity-while-the-rest-is-in

Comment: @IllegalArgument rotation is sutable for my purpose, you can post it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[android:rotation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:rotation)** for your purposes. Apply it to your root view in xml or from java.