# Different Configurations in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a viewpager which contains some number of fragments. Now  I want to restrict few fragments to Potrait mode and keep others rotatable.

I tried 
     `getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);` 
 and

 `getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED);`

in specific fragment's setUserVisibleHint() but it doesn't help. Any other way I can achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried the suggestions on where to call `setRequestedOrientation()` under http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12704009/setting-the-orientation-for-only-1-fragment-in-my-activity-while-the-rest-is-in ?

Answer (score 1):

In the xml files for the fragments that you want to restrict to portrait, add

```
android:orientation="vertical"
```

in the header for your layout. This should allow you to restrict individual fragments.

Comment: That is awesome! I didn't know we can control orientation from layout. I will give it a try, Thanks!