# How to lock the screen orientation of the fragment to landscape at runtime

Tags: android, fragment, android-orientation

I have an activity whose ist fragment is set to normal potrait orientation but on loading the second fragment, I need to lock the orientation of the second fragment to landscape. Is it possible to do that?

This is my java fragment class

```
public class DeputationsFragment extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{
    LinearLayout ll;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    SessionManager sessionManager;
    CheckBox checkBox;
    Spinner reportType;
    String[] reportTypes,reportCodes;
    String reportCode;




    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_deputations, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        sessionManager=SessionManager.NewInstance(getActivity());
        ll=(LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.ll1);
        recyclerView=(RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        checkBox=(CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.sno);
        reportType=(Spinner)view.findViewById(R.id.spin_report);
        reportType.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        if(Constants.isOnline())
        {
            getTypes();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        reportCode=reportCodes[i];
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

    }


    private void getTypes()
    {
        AsyncHttpClient client=new AsyncHttpClient();
        String url=getResources().getString(R.string.urlReportType);
        Constants.showProgress(getActivity());
        client.get(url, new TextHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString, Throwable throwable) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString) {
                Constants.dismissProgress();
                try {
                    int p1 = responseString.indexOf(">"); Constants.dismissProgress();
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    int p2 = responseString.lastIndexOf("<");
                    String r = responseString.substring(p1 + 1, p2);
                    p1 = r.indexOf(">");
                    r = r.substring(p1 + 1, r.length());
                    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(r);
                    reportTypes = new String[jsonArray.length()];
                    reportCodes = new String[jsonArray.length()];
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        reportTypes[i] = (jsonObject.getString("Name"));
                        reportCodes[i] = (jsonObject.getString("Value"));
                    }
                    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, reportTypes);
                    arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                    reportType.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
                    reportType.setSelection(0);
                    reportCode = reportCodes[0];
                    getDeputations();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Constants.dismissProgress();
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
        }

    void getDeputations()
    {
        Constants.showProgress(getActivity());
        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
        String url=getResources().getString(R.string.urlDeputationRequest);
        params.put("DistrictCode","ydRRTTxkdt6Trx91pX1+cA==");
        params.put("ReportType","1");
        client.get(url, params, new TextHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString, Throwable throwable) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString) {
                try {
                    Constants.dismissProgress();
                    int p1 = responseString.indexOf(">");
                    int p2 = responseString.lastIndexOf("<");
                    String r = responseString.substring(p1 + 1, p2);
                    p1 = r.indexOf(">");
                    r = r.substring(p1 + 1, r.length());
                    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(r);
                    RecyclerDeputations recyclerDeputations=new RecyclerDeputations(jsonArray,getActivity());
                    ll.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerDeputations);
                    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {

                }
            }
        });
    }


}
```

this is the layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/ll"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:weightSum="4">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.7"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:padding="3dp"

            android:text="Report Type"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_weight="2.3"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp">
            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spin_report"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:popupBackground="@color/white"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:textSize="8sp"
                android:scrollbars="horizontal"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="8.5"
    android:background="#386FA5"
    android:id="@+id/ll1"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.3"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:text="All"
        android:background="@drawable/borders"
        android:id="@+id/sno"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:text="S.No."
        android:gravity="start"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@drawable/borders"
        android:id="@+id/serial"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:padding="3dp"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".5" />
    <TextView

        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:text="Name"
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:background="@drawable/borders"
        android:padding="3dp"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
    <TextView

        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/from"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_gravity="start"

        android:text="From"
        android:background="@drawable/borders"
        android:padding="3dp"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.4" />
    <TextView

        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/to"
        android:text="To"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@drawable/borders"
        android:padding="3dp"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.3" />

    <TextView

        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/req_date"
        android:text="Request Date"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@drawable/borders"
        android:padding="3dp"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView

        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/pending"
        android:text="Pending With"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@drawable/borders"
        android:padding="3dp"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
    <TextView

        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/remarks"
        android:text="Remarks"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@drawable/borders"
        android:padding="3dp"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: please post your code

Comment: Posted its done

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12704009/setting-the-orientation-for-only-1-fragment-in-my-activity-while-the-rest-is-in

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have implemented the same functionality myself. My app is locked to Portrait mode for all fragments except one. In order to achieve the correct functionality I use `android:screenOrientation="nosensor"` for the activity (in the Manifest file) preventing orientation changes due to the user rotating the device.

I also use `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"` to prevent the activity to restart when the orientation is changed. Otherwise, it's easy to end up in a loop where the activity restarts, goes into the correct fragment and changes the orientation again, repeat.

In the Fragment's `onResume()` method I call `getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);` and in it's `onPause()` I call `getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);`

Hope this helps you!

Comment: I am gonna implement this and then tell u the result. Just gimme 10 mins mate

Comment: Great answer mate. You are a rockstar.

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this on your `onCreate` to set `Landscape` programmatically on your `activities or fragments`.

**Activity**

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);
```

**Fragment**

After rootView in your java add this line

```
getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

Comment: This one lock the whole activity to a specific orientation

Answer (score 1):

Orientation attribute is per activity so you can declare the orientation for only the activity that contains the fragment so that it is in landscape and the rest of the activities will remain as they are.

So you need set orientation in onCreateView of each fragment
Plse Check below code:

FragmentA

```
 public class FragmentA extends Fragment {


        @Override

        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);
            changeFragmentOrientation();


            return view;

        }

    }

public void changeFragmentOrientation(){
getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
}
```

FragmentB

```
public class FragmentB extends Fragment {


            @Override

            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

                View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_b, container, false);
                changeFragmentOrientation();


                return view;

            }

        }

    public void changeFragmentOrientation(){
    getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Override function setUserVisibleHint() in second fragment then use the below code

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if(isVisibleToUser) {
        Activity curActivity = getActivity();
        if(curActivity != null){ 
             curActivity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
         }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this would be the best option then.

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
if(isVisibleToUser) {
    Activity a = getActivity();
    if(a != null)     a.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
 }
}
```

good luck with ur project:)

Comment: It's a `Fragment`, you don't need declare `Fragments` on `AndroidManifest.xml` then... the answer is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Add in manifest
**android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"**

add in your fragment

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(@NonNull Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    if (getActivity() != null) {
        if (isViewProfileOrNot) {
            if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
                getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
            } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
                getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
            }
        }

    }

}
```