# Is this possible to override screen orientation in fragment

Tags: android, youtube, screen-orientation

My whole android application use portrait screen orientation. That's why I set **`android:screenOrientation="portrait"`** for my Activity in application manifest. But now I'm going to implement YouTubePlayerFragment.

I think it will be critically necessary to make it possible to rotate screen in this fragment so user can watch YouTube in fullscreen.

Is this possible to keep using **`screenOrientation="portrait"`** in manifest and override it somehow in one fragment ?  Is there any solution that don't require setting screenOrientation for every fragment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

within that fragment use:

**To set Orientation - Landscape**

```
getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

**To set Orientation - Portrait**

`getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);`

Also, take a look here:
[Setting the orientation for only 1 fragment in my activity while the rest is in portrait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12704009/setting-the-orientation-for-only-1-fragment-in-my-activity-while-the-rest-is-in)

Comment: Thanks a lot Max. It will set orientation for current activity, that's why i have to call setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) in fragment onDetached(), is that correct ?

Comment: Not only, you will have to add  android:configChanges="orientation" In AndroidManifest file for the activity you want to handle this orientation

In activity use onConfigurationChange overrided method. Do task you want to handle in orientation change.