# How to set fragment orientation landscape when video played?

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments, android-videoview, landscape

I have created a video player when I play video player fragment is automatically get closed. I have set player fragment orientation landscape in oncreate method. thanks in advance.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate of
[Setting the orientation for only 1 fragment in my activity while the rest is in portrait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12704009/setting-the-orientation-for-only-1-fragment-in-my-activity-while-the-rest-is-in)

It would be better if you created a separate activity and set its orientation to landscape in the manifest.